# Lumia 925 doesn't start up, Lumia Software Recovery don't support it anymore

Tags: lumia, lumia-925, recovery-tool

My Lumia 925 is dead. It freezed some time ago while I was using it, after soft reset it showed "Nokia" sign a few times and then become completely dead (doesn't react to pressing any button, nothing on screen, doesn't vibrate as it usually does on startup)

I've read some tips in internet, but none of them seem to work. I tried `VolDown+PowerBtn` but nothing happens even when phone is connected to charger. I connected it to PC and *something happened*: Windows started to install some drivers.

So I decided to download `Lumia Recovery Tool` and then I learned that my phone is no longer supported...

Is there something else I can do to fix my phone?

Answer (score 1):

Lumia Software Recovery Tool is very outdated. You should be using the current version of the software, which is the [Windows Device Recovery Tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12379/windows-10-mobile-device-recovery-tool-faq). I've had good success using this tool with a wide range of devices, including a 925. Nonetheless, be aware that it can only fix stuff that boils down to code/data problems (bad firmware, file system corruption, various other forms of bit-rot, sure; hardware damage or failure, no).

The 925 is a quite old device, and I believe out of official support now (although WDRT should still support it); while I'm all for keeping machines going as long as they will, it might be worth upgrading at this point. At some point, the effort to keep an old device usable is more "expensive" than just getting a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I will strongly suggest you to take your mobile to nearest Nokia care OR Microsoft device care centre. They will try to recover your mobile through their recover tool and maybe you will get your phone fixed. Check out following link to find nearest store. 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/locations/mobile-devices